# How can I put validations on a SQL table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Problem Assumption:**

I have a table in SQL Server, with the structure as follows;

```
Column 1: Id | INT | NOT NULL | Auto-Identity
Column 2: Name | VARCHAR(20) | NOT NULL
Column 3: Number | SMALLINT | NOT NULL
```

**Solution Scenario:**

What I want is that whenever some value is entered in a column, then it should be verified or validated against certain checks, at database level itself?

Example:

The column 3, `Number`" should only allow:

- numeric values
- with length 10
- and value should start with the digit 4

Could anyone please suggest the best way to implement this at database level?

Comment: How can smallint be length 10 when it is -32768 to +32767? And if you mean int then values of length 10 will break it. Does the length 10 and starts with 4 include sign?

Comment: the max length will be 1 to 10 or exactly 10 ?

Comment: If column 3 should have 10 digits, and start with a 4 - is it actually a number? By which I mean, is it something that you're going to perform mathematical operations against (`SUM()`, `*`, `-`, etc). If not, and it's meaning is entirely in the characters, store it as a `char`, not a numeric type.

Comment: @gbn: It was just an example.... The need of the question was to know how to put validations on table columns.

Comment: @marc_s: Thank you, will do so and keep in mind for future questions.

Comment: @Damien: Thank you, you are right it should be a character. The need of the question was to know how to put validations on table columns.

Comment: @Tathagat Verma: the question doesn't make sense because of a poor example: you ask help from experts and we spot inconsistencies. What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `number` column should be fixed-width text e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
 Id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
 Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- presumably a candidate key
 Number CHAR(10) NOT NULL
    CHECK (Number LIKE '4[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
)
```

Comment: Sorry, Should Number be Numeric(10) to be more precise ?

Comment: @SQL: I think it should be `CHAR(10)`. I suspect the `Number` in question is like account number or employee number i.e. not intended for mathematical manipulation and therefore more suited to text data.

Answer (score 3):

Use CHECK constraints - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD CONSTRAINT tenDigitsStartsWithFour CHECK
(Col3 BETWEEN 4000000000 AND 4999999999) -- Col3 must be a BIGINT, thanks Mikael
```

Comment: +1 Data type for col3 should be bigint and then you could use `Col3 between 4000000000 and 4999999999` as the check constraint.

Comment: @Mikael Derp, my brain wasn't working properly. That's much better

Comment: Thank you, works well for the specific scenario. The need of the question was to know how to put validations on table columns.